# List.add() not adding values at the end. Sorts internally

Tags: apex

I am trying to add values to a list iterating through a for loop like this.

```
List<String> leftvalues = new List<String>();
for(OpportunityLineItem  o: OLI_List)
{
    //Gets product name from map and adds to list
    leftvalues.add(pbeId_PrNameMap.get(o.PricebookEntryId));
    System.debug('*****Leftvalues:'+leftvalues);
}
```

Strangely its sorting internally after adding instead of adding at the end of list each time.
What am i doing wrong .

Debug log results:

> 05:29:24.463
>   (463698000)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|*****Leftvalues:{17TBUPGRADE}
>
> 05:29:24.464
>   (464053000)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|*****Leftvalues:{17TBUPGRADE,
>   5UPB-C10/W}
>
> 05:29:24.464
>   (464397000)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|*****Leftvalues:{17TBUPGRADE,
>   5UPB-C10/W, IFU-PN100M}
>
> 05:29:24.464
>   (464739000)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|*****Leftvalues:{17TBUPGRADE,
>   5UPB-C10/W, CBK-UPG01, IFU-PN100M}

Why did new value **CBK-UPG01** go to third position instead of fourth.?

How to prevent it from re positioning itself within the list ?
Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: can you share the whole method?

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, but what I'm starting to wonder is if you can rely on the conversion from list<string> -> string when you are printing it with System.debug. Could you verify after the for-loop that the values are infact out of order (by for-looping through the list)?

Comment: agree with @haagen

Comment: Lists are guaranteed to be ordered, also when casting to String. Will you extend debugging by logging `o` value as well? I bet the issue is with the order of `OLI_List`.

Answer (score 13):

The code that you've provided doesn't match the debug log. Maybe someone concurrently changed the code while you were running it, or you're just testing us ;-) It doesn't really matter - the question is a great puzzle!

Let's have a quick look at the documentation. First of all, [Lists are guaranteed to be ordered](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm) and [the method `add` always puts an element at the end of a List](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_List_add.htm). The described behavior would mean a serious bug in the Salesforce `List` implementation, that has been used by almost every APEX program for ages with no complains.

Even more important clue is given the kind of brackets in the debug log. [The specification of `String.valueOf`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_valueOf_7.htm) suggests that Lists are serialized using parentheses **( )**, and a quick test shows that curly brackets **{ }** are reserved for Sets.

**Conclusion:** the debug log presents an algorithm using a `Set`. By the way it's worth noting that in Salesforce Sets [are implemented using hashes and *do not* guarantee any order](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) (but it might happen that `Set` values are sorted when casting to String).

Comment: Good catch - I learned something new here!

Comment: Such a good answer. Such a shame the OP didn't take the time to accept your answer.